Bloomberg Macro "RefreshEntireWorksheet" - runs fine when I open Excel manually, but I get a Run-time error '1004' when I open Excel programatically
I have a very simple macro in Excel that calls "RefreshEntireWorksheet" from the Bloomberg Excel Add-In. This carries out the same process as clicking on "Refresh Worksheet" in the Bloomberg ribbon.

Here is my macro:
Sub Refresh_Bloomberg()

Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"

End Sub

When I open Excel manually the macro runs fine. My issue starts when I open Excel programmatically through Python (either with xlwings or win32). After opening Excel in Python, if I try to run the macro I am met with a Run-time error '1004'. This happens whether I call the macro in Python or run it manually in Excel.

There is obviously something missing between the manual opened Excel and the instance started by Python. I have checked to see whether there are Add-Ins missing and there don't seem to be. I have also included some script in the macro to first load the necessary Add-Ins. This also hasn't worked. Has anyone experienced this problem and knows how to fix it?

You definitely need to load the necessary add-in programmatically. Can you share the script you're using?

The add-in probably does not get loaded when called from python.

As per @BigBen. For a longer answer, when you open Excel via COM (as you do with win32com or xlwings), the command line used by the COM system to start Excel has the /automation argument, which tells Excel it is being used programmatically, and not to load any addins. Incidentally this is actually handy to have as a pinned application in the TaskBar, if you want to have a "clean" Excel with no addins loaded: it will launch rapidly too.

I thought it would be Add-In related but I can't pinpoint it. Here is my script:
import win32com.client as win32 excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application") excel.Visible = True wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"path.xlsm") input("...") excel.Application.Run("Auto_Snaps.Refresh_Bloomberg") wb.Close(SaveChanges=False) excel.Quit()
I also added this to my macro to check which Add-Ins were installed:
 For i = 1 To Application.AddIns.Count         Debug.Print Application.AddIns(i).Name    Next
The list was the same whether I opened Excel manually or programmatically.

Before you Open your own Workbook, Open c:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla (or wherever your Bloomberg is installed)

Also, you will probably need some kind of Wait in your Python code, then a Calculate. The Bloomberg refresh is asynchronous, so you may not have all the results back before you Close the file. Putting a Wait on the Python side does not block the Excel execution (unlike a simple sleep in the VBA). Lots of SO Bloomberg questions on this topic  ...

@DS_London you've cracked it, thanks so much. Including addin = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla") before opening the Workbook fixed the issue. I then just had to include addin.Close(SaveChanges=False) at the end to make sure that BloombergUI.xla closed. Noted on the Wait while Excel refreshes. Thanks again.
